# Can I implement web mapping application for drawing using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I want to implement a web mapping application for drawing using differents functions of topographic computation like for example calculate the "bearing angle" (gisement in frensh).I know that I can draw shapes using leaflet draw plugin but I'm wondering if leaflet provide this functions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet has a [`distanceTo()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#point-distanceto) method for the Cartesian distance between two points.

Leaflet doesn't have complicated geometric functionalities built in, but there's an excellent Leaflet plugin called `Leaflet.GeometryUtil` that does: https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil.  (And here's a link to the plugin's [online documentation](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/)).

Other plug-ins that might provide useful functionality are found here: 
http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geoprocessing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, yep I think this plug-ins are useful :)